# How to find the spherical coordinates limits calculate the volume of the solid region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The solid bounded below by the hemisphere $\rho=1,$ $ 0\leq z$ and above by the cardoid of revolution $\rho=1+\cos\phi$
I am new to the triple integral in spherical coordinates. 
I know that limits of $\rho$ will be $1\leq\rho\leq 1+\cos\phi$, the limits on $\theta$ will be $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$. So the integral will be
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{?}^{?}\int_{1}^{1+\cos\phi}(\rho)^2\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$
But how to find the limits of $\phi$ in this case, I don't know.
Can anyone help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for the cardioid of revolution, $\rho\ge1$ for $0\le\phi\le\pi/2$ and $\rho<1$ for $\pi/2<\phi\le\pi$. It intersects the hemisphere only in the $xy$ plane. Therefore, $0\le\phi\le\pi/2$.

Comment: Sir the limits on the $\rho$ and $\theta$ I have written are correct?

Comment: @NoorAslam They are correct